# Using two paint methods in two jpanels in one jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

I recently stumbled upon a problem when attempting to create an overlay for my frame. The frame consists of 2 panels, a `GamePanel` and an `OverlayPanel`, each with their own `paint` methods. I seperated these in order to keep my code cleaner and for efficiency. The problem I'm having now, though, is that my `paintComponent` methods are overlapping each other, causing only one painted panel to be visible at a time.

I understand that this is caused most likely due to the fact that both panels cover the entirety of the screen. What is being painted on the `OverlayPanel`, however, only covers a part of the screen.

The goal is that the `GamePanel` will draw a map of some sort and the `OverlayPanel` will then draw something such as a rectangle at a given location on top of this map.

Is my approach to this wrong, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my approach to this wrong, ..

Yes. It is possible to separate drawing operations into separate methods in separate classes, yet still have the entire paint operation done by a single method.

Imagine there is a `Map` class with a `draw(Graphics2D)` method, and a `RectangularPlayer` class also with a `draw(Graphics2D)` method. Each class knows how to draw its own parts to a common graphics instance. In the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of the `GameField` class, call the relevant draw methods of the map and player classes, as well as any other game elements that need to be rendered.